# How can I create a numeric field where the focus out adds 3 decimal digits?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, decimal

I have a text field:

```
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <BzTextField
        fullWidth
        label="dec"
        value={company.dex}
      />
    </Grid>
```

what I am trying to do is to create a new component so I can create a new input type number which must add 3 decimal digits  (ex. 3.3 becomes 3.300). I am having problem with how to implement something like this. Should I use Hooks or is there an easier way.

also the validation should be onChange and not on keyUp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by creating a controlled input and using input's onBlur feature, which will execute onBlur function when you are done editing the input. This function will change add 3 decimal digits to the number.

```
function App() {
const [input, setInput] = React.useState("")
const onBlur = () => {
    setInput(parseFloat(input).toFixed(3))
}
return (
<div >
    <body>
        <input
            type="number"
            value={input}
            onChange={e=>setInput(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={onBlur}
        />
    </body>
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
const x = 3.3;
const y = x.toFixed(3);
console.log(y);

// result 3.300
```

> **Explanation:**
> here `toFixed(n)` method used to extend value.
> *Where `n` is the number you want to extend value of number.*

> [Click here for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it using material. I made the assumption that you don't want the text formatted until focus leaves the control. The onChange event in material fires on every key press so this makes it difficult to format using that event alone.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

const BzTextField = ({ defaultValue = '' }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue);

    const handleBlur = (e) => {
        let parsedValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);

        if (parsedValue) {
            setValue(parsedValue.toFixed(3));
        }
    }

    return (
        <TextField
            type="number"
            fullWidth
            label="dec"
            value={value}
            onBlur={handleBlur}/>    
    );
};

export default BzTextField;
```